# Display label inside Stacked bar chart

Tags: flot

I'm trying to display the customized label inside the bar chart. No idea on how to do this.. Please help me. Label should be displayed inside each bar

Answer (score 1):

You just specify this in Series config... It's working fine for me:

```
  label: {
      display: 'outsideEnd',
        field: 'data1',  // field name
        orientation: 'horizontal',  //  or 'vertical'

         color: '#0000FF',
        'text-anchor': 'middle'
    },
```